# How to show that the curve $ay^2=x(x-a)(x-b)$ has two and only two points of inflexion?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Show that the curve $$ ay^{2}=x(x-a)(x-b) $$ has two and only two points of inflexion

This is a question that I have stumbled upon while going through the book
`Differential Calculcus by Shanti Narayan and Dr P.K. Mittal`.
How I approached the problem was to change the equation to
$$ y=\ \pm\ \sqrt{\frac{1}{a}x(x-a)(x-b)} $$
Then I went on to find the 2nd derivative of `y` and equated it to `0` which gave me the biquadratic equation
$$ 3x^{4}\ -\ 4\left(a+b\right)x^{3}\ +\ 6abx^{2}\ -\ a^{2}b^{2}\ =\ 0 $$
After this I got stuck. I tried out many ways like the Descarte's rule of signs, but none of them gave me the actual solution.
It would be very helpful if you could help me out with this problem.

Comment: Hint: Consider the relationship between the roots and what your two possible roots could be.

Comment: @MathsWizzard Sorry.... But I couldn't find any relationships. Can you help me with that? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I will present here I think is the easiest to grasp. As you have correctly calculated we have

$$g(x)=f''(x)= 3x^4 − 4(a+b)x^3 + 6abx^2 − a^2b^2  .$$

We aim to show there are two unique solutions. We will try to get a sense for the graph by trying to figure out where the turning points of $g$ are at. We have

$$g'(x)=12x^3-12x^2(a+b)+12abx=12x(x^2-x(a+b)+ab)$$ the solutions of which are $x=0$ and $x=a$ and $x=b$.  We have $g(0)=-a^2b^2$ and  $g(a)=-a^2(a-b)^2$ and $g(b)=-b^2(a-b)^2$. Thus all turnining points have negative coordinates. Taking into account that $\lim_{x\rightarrow ± \infty} g(x) $ tends to positive infinity in both cases, we have the following graph

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhXn5.jpg).

From it, we clearly see that there are two solutions

Comment: From Descarte's rule of signs we can see that one of the roots is -ve which in turn implies the other real root to be `+ve`. From the graph it is evident that the `-ve` real root is less than both a & b and the +ve root is greater than both of them. Which means that $$ \frac{1}{a}x\left(x-a\right)\left(x-b\right) $$ is +ve only at one of these cases depending on the sign of a. In that case, the + or - sign gives us two inflection points as (x, y) and (x, -y). Which means that I am going to mark your solution as the right solution :D. Thanks a lot @MathsWizzard